# Hibernate concat_ws and null fielnds

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, concat-ws

Im using CONCAT_WS within hibernate query, 
to create a giant string and search by all fields using `like '%value%'` . It works fine, but for some records some fields are null. e.g if `actId` is null, my whole concat_ws returns null. I don't know why, concat_ws must ignore null values. May be it's because hibernate trying to call getActNumber from null? anyway I'm trying hard to resolve this problem.

```
  where CONCAT_WS("_", actItemId.actId.actNumber, DATE_FORMAT(recordDate, '%d.%m.%Y'), actItemId.techniqueId.name, fzkActNumber, ....etc) like '%value%'
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was implicit usage of INNER JOINs in my query.

It does not select any parent rows without associated child. 
Solution was LEFT JOINs

```
select distinct(t) from InvBook as t                            +
                  "left join t.actItemId as actItem          "  +
                  "left join t.actItemId.actId as act        "  +
```

etc...

even if `actItemId` or `actId` is `null` now, 
CONCAT_WS ignores it and glues other fields together.

Thanks to Vlad Mihalcea https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/concat-ws-like-value/428

Answer (score 0):

`CONCAT_WS()` is functioning as designed.

If you want it to work even when some args are NULL, do something like this to convert each possibly-NULL arg to a space.

```
CONCAT_WS('_',  IFNULL(cola,''), IFNULL(colb,'') ...)
```

Comment: I tryed 
IFNULL, 
CASE when then
IF(condition?, true, false)
nothing works.
I guess somehow I need to check whether actId is null or not before getting actNumber.